# What do I do to debug: getting "Error in colSums(wts[, i] * x * pw)" after run svyby with a sdr weight?

Tags: r, survey

I was running a survey data using survey package. This is how I applied the weight

```
test <- svrepdesign(data=trial, type="other", weights=~pwgtp, repweights=weights, scale = 4/ncol(weights), rscales=rep(1, ncol(weights)), type.= "total")
```

also:

```
trial <- read_dta("OR-WA-ACS_v3.dta")
trial <- trial %>%
   subset(age_grp %in% age_0)
```

I got:

```
 svytotal(~pov_grp, test)
```

> Error in colSums(wts[, i] * x * pw) : 
>     dims [product 45864] do not match the length of object [52221]
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In wts[, i] * x :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

This is the Github [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cran/survey/master/R/surveyby.R) of this function...could not help me to understand it.

Thank you so much for your help! This is really bothering me.

Following up:
when I run svyby on some variable, for example, svyby(formula=~pov_grp, by=~hhl, design = test, FUN=svymean)..it gives me really messy table [messy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gJFe.png) instead of a good one [good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WNTS.png)

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your data with `dput`?

Comment: hi, looks like you're using the american community survey.  `library(survey)` and `dplyr` don't always work together perfectly, and subsetting prior to creating the survey design creates errors.  maybe start here?  http://asdfree.com/american-community-survey-acs.html

Comment: Thank you! It is really helpful. 
I have following up question: see above